# How to show (zero) shipping costs in WordPress Woocommerce for downloadable products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use WordPress/Woocommerce to sell downloadable products. Thus, there are no shipping costs at all. However, for legal reasons I have to show "Shipping costs: 0.00€" on the shopping cart page as well as in the order summary on the checkout page. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

1. set the product not to be "Virtual" (uncheck the box)
2. Make sure you have "Free Shipping" method
3. Change the title of this method to 0.00€

[image]
This should be it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create zero shipping cost by creating shipping rules for downloadable product and create shipping method for that.

For more details please see this video : [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONe6vxlzc51eMav7IrbIudbGVc6LqybC/view)

I hope it will help you.

Thanks